# Rails 3.1 pass data through a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, I've a '**warehouse**' model that own several fields such as  id,name,description, etc, and a boolean field called 'done'.

In my view, I want to insert a button or link field,which, when clicked, should set (through HTTP POST method) warehouse.done = true
How can I do this?

Notes: User cannot input warehouse.done field so I suppose to pass it to application as hidden field

Comment: Yes, Ajax it's ok for me

Comment: I have updated the answer friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a couple of assumptions on the views, controller.

html

```
<a href="#" id="set-warehouse-done"> DONE </a>
<input id="warehouse-id" type="hidden" value="24">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#set-warehouse-done').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/warehouse/' + $('#warehouse-id').attr('value');
      type: 'POST'
      data: done: true
    });
  });
}
```

warehouse_controller.rb

```
def update
  @warehouse = Warehouse.find(params[:id])
  if params[:done]
    if @warehouse.update_attributes(:done, params[:done])
      flash[:notice] = 'Warehouse updated successfully'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Could not update warehouse'
```

Comment: OK, in my view I wrote: 
<%= link_to "Done", :method => :post, :values => { :done => 
true } %>; how can I modify view according to your code?

Answer (score 3):

Use link to with remote option.

```
<%= link_to "Vote", {:controller=>"your_controller_name", :action => 'vote',:id=>@warehouse.id, :vote=>true}, :remote=> true, :method => :put %>
```

In your controller

```
def vote
  @warehouse = Warehouse.find(params[:id])
  @warehouse.update_attribute(:vote, params[:vote])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In your routes file

```
resources :your_controller_name do
  collection do
   put 'vote'
  end
end
```

In your voting view page add new DIV to display flash notice.

```
<div id="flash_notice" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Create new RJS template "vote.js.erb" with following code.

```
$("#flash_notice").html("You have voted successfully");
$("#flash_notice").show("slow");
```

Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Thank you my friend, now it's works. Another thing : if I want show  a flash notice once user click on "vote" link how should I do?

Comment: Hi friend, another little question.  All It works all well; the only thing I want that after jquery You have voted successfully", application redirect to another web app page; In my 'vote' controller I've tried to add:  format.html { redirect_to(@warehouse) } or  format.html { redirect_to("www.stackoverflow.com") } but it doesn't works in both case; in both case I'm not able to see jquery message too